# How to calculate distance using geopandas

Tags: geopandas

I wanted to calculate the distance from Manila to cities in the Philippines using geopandas GeoSeries.distance(self, other) function.

Steps:

```py
# So I start with the dataset, which should produce a geopandas dataframe consisting basically of cities and a polygon of its boundaries in latlong.

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/macoymejia/geojsonph/master/MuniCities/MuniCities.minimal.json'
df1 = gpd.read_file(url)

# then I define a centroid column
df1['Centroid'] = df1.geometry.centroid

# then I define Manila location as a shapely point geometry, which produces a DataFrame with point geometry and address as columns
manila_loc = gpd.tools.geocode('Manila')

# then I try to calculate the distance
df1.Centroid.distance(manila_loc.geometry)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```py
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-76585915942f> in <module>
----> 1 df1.Centroid.distance(manila_loc.geometry)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Coursera/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5137             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5138                 return self[name]
-> 5139             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5140 
   5141     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'distance'
```

I'm new to GeoPandas but I thought from the documentation that distance method can act on GeoSeries and that df1.Centroid and manila.geometry are valid shapely geometry objects. So I don't know what I am missing. Help pls.

Comment: You need to create a `Point` object that represents Manilla. And don't forget to make sure you're working in an appropriate CRS

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
# relevant code only
dists = []
for i, centr in df1.Centroid.iteritems():
    dist = centr.distance( manila.geometry[0] )
    dists.append(dist)
    print("Dist2Manila: ", dist)
```

To create new column for the distances:

```
df1["Dist2Manila"] = dists
```

Comment: You won't get reasonable distances if the projection is not equi-distance type.

Comment: I don't think you need a loop here

Comment: @PaulH Need steps for comments/debug purposes. Get it work first, optimize the code later.

Answer (score 0):

You need to feed a singular `Point` object to the distance method:

```py
from shapely.geometry import Point
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame

destination = Point(5, 5)

geoms = map(lambda x: Point(*x), [(0, 0), (3, 3), (4, 1), (8, 2), (1, 10)])
departures = GeoDataFrame({'city': list('ABCDE'), 'geometry': geoms})
print(departures.assign(dist_to_dest=departures.distance(destination)))
```

Which give me:

```
  city                  geometry  dist_to_dest
0    A   POINT (0.00000 0.00000)      7.071068
1    B   POINT (3.00000 3.00000)      2.828427
2    C   POINT (4.00000 1.00000)      4.123106
3    D   POINT (8.00000 2.00000)      4.242641
4    E  POINT (1.00000 10.00000)      6.403124
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it. I mistakenly assumed that since it is a geopandas data frame, the centroid column will already be treated as such. But I think you have to explicitly define it. So it's what I did. A minor revision on the original code from:

```
df1.Centroid.distance(manila_loc.geometry)
```

to:

```
gpd.GeoSeries(df1.Centroid).distance(manila_loc.iloc[0,0])
```

It worked.